# Where is the main font located in MacTeX?

Tags: fonts

I wish to edit the main font "Computer Modern" in FontForge to add several custom symbols, and swap them with the unused keys/symbols. Where is the font located?

Comment: You can find the font's on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm

Comment: make sure you save any edited font under a _new_ name.

Comment: Yes I know about the fonts. But can I tweak the original application's font?